# How to hide and show information according to a given ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can already hide/show elements in my script, but not properly. Each element has a unique data attribute. I also gave them an ID to reunite all elements in the same variable. But when I conselo-log my var named "roleId", it will output only the first data attribute element, which is why my mouseover event only works for the first item as shown above:

HTML:

```
<div id="#role" data-role="1">
  <span class="default">Default Content</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div id="#role" data-role="2">
  <span class="default">Default Content 2</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 2</span>
</div>

<div id="#role" data-role="1">
  <span class="default">Default Content</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div id="#role" data-role="3">
  <span class="default">Default Content 3</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 3</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var role = $('*#role');

role.mouseover(function(){
  roleId = role.attr('data-role');
  console.log(roleId); // Will output 1
  var roleHash = $('[data-role="' + roleId + '"]');
  roleHash.find('.default-content').addClass('hidden');
  roleHash.find('.mouseover-content').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: **Id must be unique** and remove `#` from `id=#role`.

Comment: The unique data I'm gathering from each element is [data-role]. The #role ID, as I mentioned in my post, is used to select all elements and they're supposed to be the same after all.

Comment: You can't use the id's that way.  Id's MUST be unique.

Comment: I see what you mean about the IDs, thanks :)

Comment: What if you were to use `id` in place of "data-role", and `class` in place of id?

Comment: you know, cause `class` don't have to be unique.

Comment: @TWFPSP I have posted a working code sample. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

Instead of repeating `Id's` use class say `role` and then try this:

```
var roles = $('.role');
roles.mouseover(function(){ 
    roleId = $(this).attr('data-role'); //use $(this)
    console.log(roleId); 
    //var roleHash = $('[data-role="' + roleId + '"]'); //no need
    $(this).find('.default-content').addClass('hidden'); //use $(this)
    $(this).find('.mouseover-content').removeClass('hidden'); //use $(this)
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/n0cfdxup/1/)

Comment: Tried that but roleId will still output the first element data attribute (which is 1)

Comment: @TWFPSP..creating a fiddle for you.

Comment: @TWFPSP  are you sure you implemented the code correctly? This should work

Comment: I didn't notice you edit your comment, it worked! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @TWFPSP..happy to help you..:)

Comment: @TWFPSP..if any one answer from this page worked for you then plz accept the answer so that qus/ans help others also...;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class and also you are using # in id in html which is not correct.

HTML with use of class will be like this :

```
<div class="role" data-role="1">
  <span class="default">Default Content</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div class="role" data-role="2">
  <span class="default">Default Content 2</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 2</span>
</div>

<div class="role" data-role="1">
  <span class="default">Default Content</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div class="role" data-role="3">
  <span class="default">Default Content 3</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 3</span>
</div>
```

And your jQuery code will be :

```
$('.role').mouseover(function(){ 
    roleId = $(this).data('role');//use jquery data API 
    console.info(roleId); 

    //uninitialize mouseover effect so that if someone mouseovered on a .role before it should show like default
    $('.role').each(function(index){
         $(this).find('.default-content').removeClass('hidden');
         $(this).find('.mouseover-content').addClass('hidden');
    });


    $(this).find('.default-content').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.mouseover-content').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```js
$('.role').mouseover(function(){ 
            roleId = $(this).data('role');//use jquery data API 
            console.info(roleId); 

            //uninitialize mouseover effect so that if someone mouseovered on a .role before it should show like default
            $('.role').each(function(index){
                 $(this).find('.default-content').removeClass('hidden');
                 $(this).find('.mouseover-content').addClass('hidden');
            });
            
            
            $(this).find('.default-content').addClass('hidden');
            $(this).find('.mouseover-content').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="role" data-role="1">
          <span class="default">Default Content</span>
          <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="role" data-role="2">
          <span class="default">Default Content 2</span>
          <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 2</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="role" data-role="1">
          <span class="default">Default Content</span>
          <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="role" data-role="3">
          <span class="default">Default Content 3</span>
          <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 3</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in html, `id` must be unique. No same `id`s can be in the same html file or odd things would happen.

instead of using `id="role"`, use `class="role"`. and use class selector, which is `$(".role")` in jquery. It will return an array of elements. you can get rid of data-attribute then. jquery support array binding, so you can bind the same function to every element in the array.

```
$(".role").mouseover(function() {
    // something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html element** Id's  cannot start from **#** , try removing the **#** from all the *div tags* and run the program.

Answer (score -1):

Since `id`'s need to be unique, you'll want to change the id of your `data-role` elements so they don't conflict (or use a data attribute like I'm doing below).

Something like this might work for you:

**HTML**

```
<div data-type="role" data-role="1">
    <span class="default">Default Content</span>
    <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div data-type="role" data-role="2">
  <span class="default">Default Content 2</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 2</span>
</div>

<div data-type="role" data-role="1">
    <span class="default">Default Content</span>
    <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content</span>
</div>

<div data-type="role" data-role="3">
  <span class="default">Default Content 3</span>
  <span class="mouseover-content hidden">Mouseover Content 3</span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $role = $('[data-type="role"]');  // prefixing vars that are jquery objects with $ is pretty common

$role.mouseover(function(){
  var roleId = $(this).data('role');
  var $roleHash = $('[data-role="' + roleId + '"]');
  $roleHash.find('.default').addClass('hidden');  // there aren't any elements with default-content class
  $roleHash.find('.mouseover-content').removeClass('hidden');
});
```